# Pygbag seems to block when downloading numpy on big projects

Tags: python, numpy, pygbag

I am trying to use pygbag on a pygame project and every time I try to run it, the site stops working after downloading numpy.

I have tried with small projects and everything seems to work just fine even when downloading numpy but when I try with my big project it just stops after downloading it, and I can't find anything that would help me understand where the problem is in the pygbag github page.
Any idea on how I could fix this ?
[Everything just stops after this line in the debug window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spT3f.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

"import numpy" should be at top of main.py

PEP722 or PEP723 - Embedding pyproject.toml in single-file scripts are not yet active. So there's no way to guess if numpy or other remote packages will be required. But if it is it must be imported first (numpy is a particularly complex specific case) so pygbag just guess from the first import lines of main.py.